# Disable config logging in Apache Flink task manager

Tags: logging, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink task manager on startup logs its config including sensetive data like credentials, that is undesirable. If there is a way to disable logging for this spefic case?

Comment: Why is it undesirable? Is it causing any issues or it is just annoyingly long?

Comment: logs may potentially be available to wide range of people, who should not have access to credentials

Answer (score 0):

Since Flink 1.10 configuration values are filtered out of the logging if their key names contain either "password" or "secret". See [FLINK-14047](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14047).